# ngx-bootstrap: date input with modal datepicker

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement an input for date that has the datepicker in a modal.
The **[docs](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#examples)** cover datepicker and modal - but not the combination.

I am sort of following **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537762/how-to-instantiate-in-angular2-ngx-bootstrap-modal-when-the-modal-is-open)**, but do I need to create a whole component for the modal? I'm not really sure how to build this.

An example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can determine, while it is certainly a very popular request, it is currently not possible.

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/273